# How to use scss variable from an imported scss file?

Tags: sass, parceljs

I'm currently trying out parcel but I came across an issue. I can't use scss variables from an imported scss file.

```sass
@import "another_file.scss";          

body {
    background-color: map-get($colors-utility, 'error');
}
```

> Error: Undefined variable: "$colors-utility".

Any Ideas?

Comment: Doublecheck that your imported file path is correct. Ensure that the map exists in the imported file. Try using a simple variable declaration like $colour-red: red; to make sure file is being imported properly. Also make sure you built your map correctly, Try using your map https://www.sassmeister.com here and see if there are errors